# Share captcha and submit button

Tags: javascript

I can't solve problem with captcha for a whole week. I found simple math captcha in google and now i need to combine two buttons:check (captcha) and send button in one button. Now when i try to send letter after correct answer on captcha i see the failure error. Any advice will be greatly appriciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
    var c = a + b
    function DrawBotBoot()
    {
        document.write("What is "+ a + " + " + b +"? ");
        document.write("<input id='BotBootInput' type='text' maxlength='2' size='2'/>");
    }    
    function ValidBotBoot(){
        var d = document.getElementById('BotBootInput').value;
        if (d == c) return window.open('','_top');        
        return alert(false);
    }
    </script>
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4>Отправьте сообщение</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="contact2" name="contact">
                    <label class="label" for="name">Имя</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="input-xlarge"><br>
                    <label class="label" for="email">E-mail</label><br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge"><br>
                    <label class="label" for="message">Сообщение</label><br>
                    <textarea name="message" class="input-xlarge"></textarea>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                       <script type="text/javascript">DrawBotBoot()</script>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Check" onclick="ValidBotBoot();"/>
                            <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Отправить" id="submit2">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: try this link [http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/html-contact-form-captcha.html](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/html-contact-form-captcha.html)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Coolprarun, thank you for link! I will play with it too. Pikand, thank you for answer, i have got error message - failure. It seems to me that ther is a conflict between two buttons - Send and check, which i can't solve.